How to handle catching various possible exceptions in PHP with each having different output?
In my router.php I throw three exceptions: 'RouteNotFoundException', 'MethodNotAllowedException', 'RoutingException'. The router then calls a controller which may have countless other custom exceptions. They all extend my main exception handler 'CustomExceptions'
In my index.php file, I have a single try/catch statement. However, for certain exceptions I want to load a view like a 404 error page. How can something like this be done without making the try/catch block extremely long?
try {
   $route->run();
} catch (PageNotFoundException $e) {
   view(404);
} catch (MethodNotAllowedException $e) {
   view(405);
} catch ...

Would it make sense to have a ResponseException that is used to extend any HTTP response status codes like 404, 405, 500, etc...? While that helps reduce the amount to catch, there's still a lot left.
try {
   $route->run();
} catch (ResponseException $e) {
   view($e->statusCode());
} catch ...


General design questions like this are probably more appropriate for [softwareengineering.se]. Here in SO we tend to avoid "best practice" questions because the answers are opinion-based rather than objective.

What you should probably do is make all those different exceptions subclasses of the general exception. That way you can use either approach as appropriate.

In your router.php, it would be possible to catch all the various types in one block, then do something different based on the exception's type.
class FooException extends Exception{

}
class BarException extends Exception{

}

function _doThing($number){
  if($number > 99){
    return $number;
  }else if($number < 50){
    throw new FooException("Threw foo");
  }else if($number > 50){
    throw new BarException("The Bar");
  }
}

try{
  _doThing(19);
}catch(Exception $ex){
  echo get_class($ex) . "\n";
  echo $ex->GetMessage() . "\n";
}


So only catch response exceptions in the router itself and all others catch in the index.php file?
